# How to filter this noise?

Tags: microcontroller, noise, esp32, emi-filtering

My ESP32 is powered using a 5 V USB wall plug. The ESP32 is connected to a stepper motor driver to run a stepper motor.

The ESP32 takes an input from digital pin 5; this pin is pulled up with a 10 kΩ resistor to 5 V (I know the ESP32 is 3.3 V) with an RC filter of 1 kΩ and 100 nF.

Every time the power is enabled to the motor this is the noise on pin 5:

[image: noise on digital IO5]

[image]

When power is cut from the motor this is the reading on IO5:

[image]

Question:
How do I get rid of this noise?

Edited:

The reason IO5 was pulled to 5 V is to offset the noise. At 3.3 V pull high with a noise of 1.6 V it will sometimes trigger IO5 to low. Hence when tied to 5 V with 1.6 V noise it is still well above the low level logic voltage.

The 5 V USB wall plug is rated for 3 A. The ESP32 is only drawing around 0.8 A at most.

I have tried the same setup with a lab bench power supply. The noise was not there when using the lab bench power supply.

The USB 5 V wall plug, oscilloscope, and motor driver are all connected to the same mains power board.

The stepper motor driver enclosure and stepper motor shell are grounded at the same point.

Comment: Is the noise a problem? Is it a real problem, or imaginary due to measurement setup? Why do you pull the voltage to 5V anyway, even if you know you should not? Would removing the pull to 5V get rid of the issue? Likely the voltage dips are caused by the high current pulses used to drive the stepper. The USB power supply may not handle pulsed loads well. But you never even said what current the USB supply can provide and how much is the load current on the motor, what if motor draws just too much current?

Comment: Hi @Justme, when I used a different power supply (my lab bench power supply) the noise didn't show up under the same testing so I doubt that this is because of the setup. Pull up to 3.3v have the same problem. Changing the 5v pull up to 3.3v does not get rid of the problem.

Comment: So, what is the problem? Please answer the above. If it works leave it is my advice unless you know it causes a specific problem.

Comment: Not mentioned is how stepper driver gets powered. GND connections to all these power sources **and** oscilloscope GND along with probing problems makes troubleshooting rather complex.

Comment: @Andyaka, the problem is that sometime there is big spike causing the io5 to read logic low.

Comment: @glen_geek stepper motor are powered from the driver. The driver are connected to mains. Stepper motor driver enclosure are grounded as well as the motor shell

Comment: @TojiMeraki - Hi, Describing the design in words, as the question does now, isn't enough detail for me (and perhaps for other site members too). I would want to see the schematic for the design, links to relevant datasheets (including for the stepper motor driver, which is guess is a module that you bought & the datasheet for the stepper motor too) and photos showing the wiring & the actual hardware setup. Please consider adding that. Thanks. (Other people might ask for more / different additional info. The list above is the *minimum* that I think is needed to even start thinking about this.)

Comment: @Justme you are the man. Just moving my oscilloscope away from the motor driver the problem went away. So the problem is that my oscilloscope picking up the emi generated from the motor driver. After I have a proper setup my circuit is clean as it gets . Much appreciated

Comment: Add a big capacitor to your power line. Add a small capacitor to your pin 5 (before the pullup resistor) Add an inductor in series before your motor. Add software filtering (debouncing) to pin 5 measurements.

Comment: @TojiMeraki - You should probably post your last comment as an answer as that was the actual solution to your problem. Posting answers in comments is not how Stack Exchange works. You should reference/quote Justme's comment in your answer. Then mark your answer as the accepted answer using the tick button next to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This noise is typical of a low cost switch mode power supply. Basic switch mode power supplies (flyback) do not respond well to current variations. This characteristic is known as the "load recovery time".

This image shows the load recovery time, in other words the voltage regulation under load transients.

[image: Voltage regulation of DC suppies under load transients]

*Source of image : [Rohde & Schwarz - Fundamentals of DC power supplies - Output characteristics](https://scdn.rohde-schwarz.com/ur/pws/dl_downloads/dl_common_library/dl_brochures_and_datasheets/pdf_1/Fundamentals-of-DC-power-supplies-Output-characteristics_fly_en_3608-8005-32_v0200.pdf) (page 5)*

One way to improve (but not perfectly) this noise, is add an energy reservoir capacitor or a higher quality power supply.

Comment: This probably isn't the correct answer: the signal shown is a ringing response, and much, much faster than most any SMPS responds (~100s µs). But, with such meager info from OP, it's hard to say for sure.